# Shotwell problem with moving files

Tags: shotwell

I am trying to consolidate all my photos under one [Shotwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotwell_%28software%29) directory. Some of my photos were copied into that folder and some where not when I imported them (some were imported in place and that is not what I want). I have written some [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) code to access the Shotwell database to help me find the files not in the correct folder.

As I understand from point 2 in *[How can I move my photo files from one directory or hard-drive to another?](http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/shotwell/wiki/ShotwellFAQ#How-can-I-move-my-photo-files-from-one-directory-or-hard-drive-to-another)* I should be able to move them, have them show up as missing, and then re-import them from the new folder. When I try and re-import them, I am told that the duplicates will not be imported and the files stay in the missing file area.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What Shotwell is meant to do in this case, is to auto-recognize them (not importing again) as soon as you have moved them somewhere under the directory where it copies the photos during import.  But I think you have to enable the auto-import feature for this to work.  Look in the Preferences, under "Library Location" there's also a check box that needs to be checked: "Watch library directory for new files".
Currently these photos are still in the database (hence the "duplicate" that does not allow it to re-import) but the file location has changed so they go "missing" under Shotwell.  Did you move them to the library defined under Preferences (or a subfolder underneath)?

Answer (score 0):

Remove ALL files from the Shotwell Library and add them again.

1. Click "Library"
2. Press `CTRL+A` (select all files)
3. Press `SHIFT+DEL` (confirm to remove only from library)
4. Add everything again!

Most of my files were already in the right place, so it didn't take so much time. Just the files in the wrong place where copied.